# Passing multiple value_list in Django

Tags: python, json, django

I have this code in views.py:

```
def pins_info(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        getpin = request.GET.get('pin', None)
        m = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(clandpin=getpin).
            values_list('landproperty__ctaxdec')
        n = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(clandpin=getpin).
            values_list('ssectionid__sbrgyid__cbrgyname')
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'taxdec': list(m),'brgy': list(n)}),
            content_type='application/json')
```

I works fine, but it is not that effective when I want to get other values. I can access the result in my template like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    taxdec = data['taxdec'];
    brgy = data['brgy'];
    var inputform = $('#forminput').val();
    if( inputform == "Select Land PIN") {
        alert('Please Select Land PIN')
    }
    else{
        $('#status').append(
            "<p>Tax Declaration: " + taxdec + "<br/>Barangay: " + brgy + "</p>"
        );
    }
}
```

How can I simplify my code to make it more effective like:

```
 m = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(clandpin=getpin).
     values_list('landproperty__ctaxdec','ssectionid__sbrgyid__cbrgyname')
```

But how do I pass it to my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take your `m` and `n` queries as:

```
m = range(5)
n = range(6, 11)
```

Then your single query of `m = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(clandpin=getpin).  values_list('landproperty__ctaxdec','ssectionid__sbrgyid__cbrgyname')` is equivalent to the structure of:

```
new = zip(m, n)
#[(0, 6), (1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 10)]
```

So you can "transpose" that:

```
zip(*new)
# [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10)]
```

Then build a `dict` from that and your keys:

```
results = dict(zip(['taxdec', 'brgy'], zip(*new))))
# {'brgy': (6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 'taxdec': (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)}
```

Then `json.dumps` results.

---

Or use an `OrderedDict` for your JSON name and column names values and generalise further:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

keyvals = OrderedDict([
    ('taxdec','landproperty__ctaxdec'),
    ('brgy', 'ssectionid__sbrgyid__cbrgyname')
])

m = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(clandpin=getpin).values_list(*keyvals.values())
result = dict(zip(keyvals, zip(*m)))
```

That way, you can add/remove columns to be selected and their associated JSON values in one place for the same query.

Comment: Thanks! I used `OrderedDict` then `json.dumps` the result. Something like this: `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result),content_type='application/json')`